# PayPal Sandbox IPN History Missing

Tags: paypal

Where is the IPN History information in PayPal (Latest 3/2013) Sandbox? I had seen it as a sub item in the History menu just after the latest Sandbox upgrade but now I can not locate it. The history allowed the resending of IPN messages. Currently I am not receiving IPN from the sandbox and am attempting to determine whether it is another PayPal Sandbox issue but have no idea whether IPN messages are being sent without the IPN history.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the IPN history is older than 28 days, you will not be able to view it.  Make sure the IPN that you are looking for is within the last 28 days.  If it is and you dont see it, can you provide me with the transaction id so that I can look into the issue.

Comment: All transactions are recent. Here are a few transaction numbers: #8K329181JU058324J
#3V892783FR3815732
#0GL55136ES0886246
#35T37092AG875470M 

Also, has the IPN History function been removed?

Comment: These transactions id's are for payments from one personal account to another personal account.  You wouldn't have an IPN section or history with personal account.  You would want to set up a business account for the seller account, not a personal account.

Comment: Actually, we have been doing this awhile now. We have created a 'cart' with the notify_url field which will create an IPN for the request without the need for a business account. Should I look up the older docs to provide a reference? Up until this latest sandbox change, this has worked without a hitch. We currently have this operating in production. Is there a way to communicate via email on this issue?

Comment: Since the functionality shouldn't be there for personal accounts, you wouldn't be able to access this section by going thru the menu on your personal account, but you could possibly access it by the direct link.  However, I would still suggest using a business account with, as once you go live you will eventually run into issues with using a personal account for a seller account.  Try accessing this link, it may not work since the feature shouldn't really be supported for personal accounts.  https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history

Comment: Our web application allows anyone with a PayPal account to provide their PayPal email address. We don't actually control what type of accounts our members have but our system needs to receive the IPN for the transactions on behalf of our members. This has been working in production without issue. We continue to receive IPN for members with any type of PayPay account, personal or otherwise by specifying a notify_url. Will this functionality cease to exist? Is there something about sandbox that will be implemented in production? Forgetting IPN history at the moment,can you tell if IPNs were sent

Comment: You may be able to receive IPN's by setting the IPN URL in the code, but you wont be able to access the IPN history through the account for personal accounts.

Comment: It was a challenge to determine the IPN issue without seeing the history. Creating a sandbox business account and adding IPN notifications helped to see and trigger the sending of IPN messages. After the internal issue was discovered, the personal accounts also properly send IPN messages. Thanks for the help